# Keyword ranking tracker that works on a per-domain basis

Tags: seo, keywords, tools, ranking, google-ranking

I'm looking for a keyword racking tracker tool for google.

I have found a lot of them over the internet. However I need one that can track the ranks of a site on domain basis (not exact full URL).  Because I'm not sure which page of my site comes up on the result depends on the keyword as my site has hundreds of pages.

Any recommendation?
Or do I have to set each URLs per keyword?

Comment: note that we don't allow polls or "best of" questions here, so try to be very specific with your requirements, and as complete as you can.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as the best tool . There are a lot of tools out there each with its particular advantages and drawbacks.

I tried a lot of them but settled for [link-assistant](http://www.link-assistant.com/rank-tracker/)'s Rank Tracking and I must say I was more than happy with it. There is also a web based tool by SEOmoz ([rank-tracker](http://www.seomoz.org/rank-tracker)) which is pretty good.

You won't find a tool that magically finds your top keywords for your site's pages. The only service that does that is Google Webmaster Tools. It is a must use for any webmaster. There you can see your top keywords but you have to pay attention to filters. Sometimes you may find a keyword that is not detected as a ranking phrase by other tools because it is a image or local related keyword for example.